# Jquery Vs Mootools which is having good performance? why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

Can any one reply me which of the javascript frameworks are better to implement on my project?
jQuery or Mootools?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a matter of what coding style do you prefer and can help you in the long term. Just because other people use jQuery doesn't make it any easier for me to learn the way that it's coded.

This is a must for you to read before you go any further: http://jqueryvsmootools.com/

Answer (score 8):

MooTools has the better API and once you actually use it, you'll see how the design choices make sense.

Try them both, but you'll stay for the extendability of MooTools

Answer (score 1):

In the [last performance comparison](http://blog.creonfx.com/javascript/mootools-vs-jquery-vs-prototype-vs-yui-vs-dojo-comparison-revised) I know of, jQuery beat MooTools on IE, and they were head to head otherwise. Of course, one year is a huge lot of time in Javascript, so that says little about their current speed.

Anyway, unless you are really sure Javascript framework performance will be important for you, I would recommend jQuery, which has clearly been the popularity winner (see eg. [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends?q=jquery%2Cmootools)), which means better community support, more eyes and more developers in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

Go with JQuery, it has the most active development community. Even MS is contributing code to the Jquery project.

Comment: `Even MS is contributing code to the Jquery project` - is there an upside do that? :)

Comment: Seriously, how about just fixing IE -- or better yet, retiring it.  jQuery is littered with IE-specific hacks, many of which reference the bug report number.

Comment: @Dimitar Christoff: the upside is that jQuery tends to be faster on IE than other frameworks.

Comment: I am sorry if I don't put too much stock in this. It's the same MS programmers we know and love that have been failing to get IE up-to speed with other browsers for ... donkeys years. Less said about other apps of theirs, the better. +1 harpo

answer this: why would IE programmers work with jquery to fix their IE-bug when they can work on IE instead?