# MooTools? What is its primary advantage?

Tags: jquery, mootools

I just happened to meet the framework and don't understand its primary advantage over other framework like jQuery. 
Can you shed some light on it? For instance, what problems will you use it to resolve?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MooTools: (My Object Oriented Tool) is Light-Weight Javascript framework.

Read a very good description here: http://jqueryvsmootools.com/

and good link: http://www.mootorial.com/wiki/mootorial/00a-mootoolsvsothers

http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-dojo-vs-mootools-dom/71 (Compare results of other browsers)

[Jquery Vs Mootools which is having good performance? why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805536/jquery-vs-mootools-which-is-having-good-performance-why)

**Quote**

> It's a matter of what coding style do you prefer and can help you in
>   the long term. Just because other people use jQuery doesn't make it
>   any easier for me to learn the way that it's coded.

Also; I reckon your question might get closed because might be for some its very Open and not-constructive question `:)`

**Image** MIght says it all

[image]

Comment: @Ricky No problems at all bruv `:)` if I may further elaborate: any language has different frameworks and same as any frameworks there are advantage and dis-advatages :) When I was in uni <not long ago> my prof. once said: If you give man a tool, he will come out with 20 different versions of it and thats the case with MooTools and many other frameworks (Good frameworks indeed) anyhoo hope this helps :)

Answer (score 5):

MooTools is an Object Oriented framework that provides classes amongst other features that help maintain a consistent coding style and create more modular code.

This allows for classical inheritance. Classes can extend other classes, additionally initialization methods may be provided.

```
var Animal = new Class({
    initialize: function(age){
        this.age = age;
    }
});
var Cat = new Class({
    Extends: Animal,
    initialize: function(name, age){
        this.parent(age); // calls initalize method of Animal class
        this.name = name;
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe provide an example to illustrate ...?

Comment: this only shows one function of MooTools (Class)

Comment: he was looking for its "primary advantage"